# Unable to change colour in UIWebView

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using the following code it is working fine if I want to make a HTML page but it is not working on `UIWebView`. it looks like don't know why web view is not rendering the HTML tags. Is there any way I can fix it?

```
 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body { color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000000; }</style></head><body>%@</body></html>",string];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Have you tried your UIWebView with a normal URL? Could be a problem with your webview setup. Show us your setup code?

Comment: UIWEbView is just an outlet here.. and yes it opens a url.. and it also opens this code but the colour is not changed. It shows only black colour as text and white background..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Helooooooo"];
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body { color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000000; }</style></head><body>%@</body></html>", string];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]